# Angular share asynchronous data across controllers and bind to views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a service which I would like to use across multiple controllers. The services is defined like this:

```
app.factory('Data', ['$http',
  function($http) {

    var Data = this;
    var theProduct = {};

    return {
      product: function() {
        return theProduct;
      },

      getProduct: function(ext_id) {

        return $http.post('get_product', {
          product_id: ext_id
        }).success(function(data) {
          theProduct = data;
        });

      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I have a form, that uses the `ProductFormController` to retrieve product data when it's submitted. That controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('ProductFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Data',
  function($scope, $http, Data) {

    /*
     * Get a product and all of it's data from the server
     */
    $scope.getProduct = function() {

      Data.getProduct($scope.extProductId).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }

  }
]);
```

Then, I have an `AppController`, which should display certain sections when a product object exists in the `Data` service.

```
<div class="row" id="productInfo" ng-show="product().id" ng-controller="AppController">/div>
```

Within `AppController`, I have this line:

```
$scope.product = Data.product;
```

I would like the `productInfo` div to show whenever a product object exists in the `Data` service, but it seems that the variable never gets updated. I've seen this question, but do not believe the accepted answer actually answers the question:

[Angular: share asynchronous service data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196802/angular-share-asynchronous-service-data-between-controllers)

Comment: Where is `ProductFormController` being used? What if the data has not been fetched yet by the time appcontroller runs?

Comment: The data has not been fetched yet, but I thought that since I am binding to a function `product().id`, that when the data is fetched, the view will update. `ProductFormController` is at the top of the page and contains a form to enter a product ID, followed by the `AppController`, which contains the rest of the app and should display results based on the product that is fetched above.

Comment: Yes it will update.. But there might be some issue in the portion of code that you are not showing us.. http://plnkr.co/edit/Hbu2J4dfKMtAcu8Mvt2Y?p=preview Check if your data actually is being fetched or not also check data's structure, if it is what you expect.

Comment: You're right it does update. And you're there was an unrelated code issue that I mistook for this issue. Thanks for making me take a second look.